# How to count each video unique views

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, session-variables

Application is written in `Zend Framework 1.12`.
My videos are available under `url`:

```
test.com/videos/video/id/1
test.com/videos/video/id/2
test.com/videos/video/id/3
...
```

where the number is a unique parameter generated from MySQL DB.
I would like to count views of each video (unique).

My video action in `VideosController` looks like:

```
public function videoAction() {
     $video_id = $this->_getParam('id', 0);
     $hits = new Application_Model_DbTable_Hits();
     $hit = $hits->fetchRow($hits->select()->where('belongs_to_video = ?', $video_id));

     if (!isset($_SESSION['views']) || !($_SESSION['views'] == $video_id){
         $_SESSION['views'] = $video_id; 
         $newViews = $hit->count + 1;
         $data = array('count' => $newViews, );    
         $hits->update($data);   
     }

}
```

It works, however, not in a right way. After visiting particular video views rise (after refreshing the site not), after going to another one views also rise (after refreshing the site not), but after coming back to the first one they rise again (they should not).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: why you keeping views in session?

Comment: indeed sessions are not good for this you need a table "view" where you store the video_id, ip, datetime.. when you can use this query to select unique views (unique ip) per video `SELECT video_id, COUNT(DISTINCT ip) FROM view GROUP BY video_id ORDER BY video_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions aren't a good solution for this. I'd recommend that you log IP address and create blocking cookies to avoid recording duplicate views.

**IP Address Logging:** This is a good method to avoid logging multiple views. All you need is to put a record in the database as soon as the viewer finishes watching the video (or whatever you count as watched) and the next time, check if the record exists in y our database.

**Blocking Cookies:** You can also put blocking cookies in your viewers' browsers. This is fairly effective to avoid recording multiple views. You need to send a cookie when a viewer watches the video and check if the cookie exists in the second attempt.

In my opinion, **IP Address Logging** is enough for this. If your website includes a membership system, you can then simply implement IP Address Logging (but instead of IP addresses, you log user_ids there).